# Flutter: Can't open telegram channel from URL_LUNCHER

Tags: flutter

I want to direct open to telegram channel using url_luncher from my flutter app.
currently, I can open the telegram app but it does not direct to the channel.

Is there any configure would need to achieve this?

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async {
      var url = Uri.parse("tg://t.me/channel_name");
      if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
        await launchUrl(url);
      }
    },
    child: ListTile(
      visualDensity: const VisualDensity(vertical: -4),
      minLeadingWidth: leadingTxtSpace,
      leading: const CircleAvatar(
        radius: 15,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: Icon(Icons.telegram_outlined, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      title: Text(
        "Telegram",
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#android

Answer (score 5):

In older version its working fine

```
url_launcher: ^6.0.12
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

After upgrading SDK & Packages facing same issue. app opened but not navigate to specific chatting screen so i found solution for whatsapp & telegram app.

```
url_launcher: ^6.1.6
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 33
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.3.6"
```

add few things inside `<queries>` in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
                       
     <!-- Place inside the <queries> element. -->
                    <intent>
                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                        <data android:scheme="https" />
                    </intent>
                    
                    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
                    <package android:name="org.telegram.messenger" />
</queries>
```

in launchURL you need to pass `mode` parameter explicitly with value: `LaunchMode.externalApplication` like this:

```
try {
    "Launch URL: $url".printLog();
    if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
      showToast(sSomethingWrong);
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    "Could not launch url $ex".printLog();
 }
```

Used URL in my app

```
String sURLTelegram = "https://t.me/user_name";
String sURLWhatsapp = "whatsapp://send?phone=";
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used this link, try that too .
https://t.me/user_name
It work in my case..

Comment: Using #https it direct to browser
but in case, I want it directs and open telegram app in  my phone sir.
is there any solution for that?

Comment: Check my answer you need pass mode parameter in your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt the example yourself

```
IconButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await launch(
                              "https://t.me/Your link",
                              forceSafariVC: false,
                              forceWebView: false,
                              headers: <String, String>{
                                'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.telegram,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                          iconSize: 45,
                        ),
```

Comment: Hello @Abdulkadir
What is key and value that you mention in headers?
Please you tell me more detail how can I get those key?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launch.html  You can read the headers field at this address.